# My adoptive father got refused UK visitor visa

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My friend adoptive father's application has been refused:

> You have applied to visit the UK for 3 days to visit your son. You
> state your named son is currently in the UK as a student. You have
> submitted adoption papers in support of your relationship, however
> Home Office records show in your named son’s most recent application
> for a UK visa, his father’s name is different to yours. The supporting
> information provided does not demonstrate your UK contact is expecting
> you on this visit or provide further detail on your relationship.
>
> You state you intend to spend £1000 (179,993DZD at £1 = 179.99DZD –
> [www.oanda.com](http://www.oanda.com) as of 31/12/2020) on this visit out of your own expense.
> You have submitted a bank statement in your name with account number
> ending 8886 with a balance of 32,661.73DZD (£181.46). I note deposits
> supporting a monthly pension income, however given the funds evidenced
> available I am not satisfied you have sufficient disposable funds to
> cover the costs of this visit. Given the above I am therefore not
> satisfied you have demonstrated that your circumstances are as
> declared or are as such that you intend to leave the UK at the end of
> your visit. This also leads me to further doubt your intentions in
> travelling to the UK. I am also not satisfied that you have sufficient
> funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to your visit without
> accessing public funds. Your application for a visit visa has
> therefore been refused under paragraphs V4.2 (a), (c) & (e).

****I now will write an explanation letter to explain that back to our home country we don't grant the family name to the adopted child due to some religious and traditional reasons.** please can you give more ideas or solutions ??
and regarding the bank statement, he has created a bank letter and has put all his savings. Is this a good idea ?? Thank you so much**

Comment: I don't see why the name traditions would explain the mentioned discrepancy? The person already being in the UK provided a different person as his father in his visa application than the person now claiming to be a father wanting to visit his son.

Comment: It's the father's name they say don't match, in that case it doesn't really matter whether the adopted child carries the family name. As for the financial reason, find one of the many other questions here aboute that.

Comment: I hope that "he has created a bank letter" is just a translation issue!

Comment: Also given the current situation and the requirement to quarantine for the whole stay, a 3 day visit is likely to be considered with a lot of suspicion. Remember that he also has to book and pay for tests while in the UK (most are in the £100-£300 range) as well as a test before leaving. Note that he can't leave the place for any reason, and needs to be in a separate room and stay away from other people in the same place. If he tests positive, anyone in the same place will have to quarantine for 10 days. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england

Comment: Hello, first of all the Home office need to understand that the cultures are different, his FATHER adopted him for some reasons (we're not gonna go into more details) he took a legal responsibility for his upbringing, and the student or the child considers him as the real father. and on the adoption certificate, it says that the biological father agrees on abondoning the child and giving consent to the adoptee (to the one who got rejected) The adoptee (his biological mother's husband) therefore would like to visit his son. For the bank statement, he has a personal bank account

Comment: this refusal was in December 2020

Comment: The family name does not matter; what matters is that the name of the father is different on the child's visa application. What name did the child put on the child's visa application form?

Comment: UKVI concluded the application was not credible, and in the basis of the information in your question that conclusion looks correct.

Comment: Suddenly transferring his savings into the account is not going to look very good.

Comment: "first of all the Home office need to understand that the cultures are different" - the Home Office are *very* aware of this, as they are also aware that cultural missteps on their part are grounds for their conclusions to be overturned by the courts, and thats something they strive to avoid.  This isn't a random company, this is a government office whose main job is to deal with foreign cultures - they don't wing it by any means.

Comment: The name issue makes this not a duplicate.

Answer (score 14):

The issue of money. The father said he would spend £1000, and then submitted bank statements that only showed he had £181.46. That was a waste of a visa application. There was no chance it would be approved.

When the father makes his next application he needs to send bank statements that show:

1. He has at least the amount he is going to spend, and has had it for many months (not recently transferred into an account)
2. His financial situation is good enough to make spending £1000 on a vacation sensible.

See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) for more details.

You are misunderstanding the name issue. It is not about whether your friend's family name is the same as his adoptive father. The problem is that your friend stated his father's name on his student application and **that name is not the same as the person making the application.** So (for example) your friend said on his student visa application that his father's name was "Stefan Ilyich", but now there is a person claiming to be his father who is called "Ivan Havel". That needs to be sorted out, and a letter talking about family name traditions will not work.